# Tags in logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

How to direct postfix logs to index postfix ?
In logstash config

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
     grok { 
}
}     
output {
if "postfix" in [tags]{
        elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "localhost:9200"
            index    => "postfix-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
}
```

In filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
      - /var/log/maillog*
  exclude_files: [".gz$"]
tags: ["postfix"]
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["10.50.11.8:5044"]
```

In the log logstash a lot

```
[WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"newrelicdata", :_type=>"_doc", :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x4ceb504a>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"newrelicdata", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"V7x2z20Bp3jq-MOqpNbt", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [host] of type [text] in document with id 'V7x2z20Bp3jq-MOqpNbt'. Preview of field's value: '{name=mail.domain.com}'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:521"}}}}}
```

Why date from mail.domain.com try to get not in index postfix ? And the data is trying to get into all the indexes ? Any help

Answer (score 0):

I think the logs contain field name "host", so it's throwing an error as "failed to parse field [host] of type [text]"

```
mutate {
   rename => ["host", "server"]
   convert => {"server" => "string"} 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand.  Here is the full config logstash postfix.conf https://pastebin.com/k6rnyjE3  Do you need a sample of Postfix logs ?

Comment: yes, i need sample of postfix logs, can you share it

Comment: Thanks. The logs of Postfix https://pastebin.com/VCZdaCXp I want to notice in the test ELK where there are no other indexes the Postfix index is created.

Comment: send me this the patterns /etc/logstash/patterns files one or two files

Comment: there is one file with such content https://pastebin.com/Y7R2n8U0

Answer (score 0):

As I tried sending the logs with the below filebeat.yml configurations,

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
  paths:
  - /home/varsha/ELK7.4/logs/*.log
  tags: ["postfix"]
 output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

By the above configurations and the files you have shared with me are working fine and got the expected result, please check it in https://pastebin.com/f6e0E52S

Comment: Excuse me, what should I check ? 
I found in indexes with which postifx conflicts such in mapping https://pastebin.com/AC2K3fRq
That is, there is a host. How to change the index postfix that instead of the host field was the server field ?